# How to pass props to a component being "styled" in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Learning MUI and following the docs pretty well. However, I'm trying to style the Paper component as in the examples, but I want the Paper component to have `elevation={3}`.

How do I pass that prop to Paper in the below code?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function BasicGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428260/use-paper-elevation-prop-via-css ?

Comment: That's useStyle from material UI version 4. Styled components are different then useStyle.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the prop and access it. within the Styled component. Remember these are mostly passed as HTML attributes so boolean works a little differently as a string.

Here's a working example at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-xv9s05?file=/index.js:257-268). You can check how we have added a border to the item based on the prop.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2";

function App() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item border={"true"}>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={4}>
          <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={8}>
          <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme, border }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#1A2027" : "#fff",
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: "center",
  border: border === "true" ? "1px solid red" : "none",
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary
}));

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```